# date object returns random date for invalid months/day

Tags: javascript, date

This code:

```
var dt = new Date('82/66/2005');
```

...gives a value for `dt` as **Wed Nov 25 1992 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)** on Firefox.

How?

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4jyT3/1/

Comment: Which browser are you using? I get an "invalid date" error in Chrome

Comment: And in FF aswell. IE returns `NaN`

Comment: The result is implementation dependent and would vary across browsers.

Comment: I bet it is Internet Explorer :)

Comment: check now. Replaced '-' with '/'. I am using chrome and FF.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - check the fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That date is not in a format that is specified to be supported by the `Date` constructor. I'm not surprised to find that most engines call it invalid, but apparently Firefox is attempting to make a date out of that. Even though it's not specified, most engines support `month/day/year` and all, last I checked, support `year/month/day`. Firefox appears to be applying `year/month/day` to the input, where most browsers see the invalid values and go with "invalid."

So Firefox is seeing `82` for year (and assuming 1982), `66` for month, and `2005` for day. JavaScript is usually very forgiving about out-of-bound values on dates, moving to the next month and such as necessary. And that's what's happening here: If you take January 1st 1982 and add a further 65 months and 2004 days, you end up on Nov 25 1992.

This code will reliably give you the date you mentioned:

```
var dt = new Date(1982, 65, 2005);
```

(65 instead of 66 because in the number form, months start with 0, but in string form, they start with 1.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't re-produce this in *Chrome*, but I'll explain how *FireFox* arrives here.

```
new Date('82-66-2005');
```

Invalid date, let's guess what you wanted based on what we know about dates.

- hyphen `-` format is usually `yyyy-mm-dd`
- `yy` is short for `19yy`
- there are `12` months, so month `13` is *Januaray* of next year
- similarly for days

So using this knowledge lets estimate it, assuming `365.25` days per year and `30.5` days per month.

```
// input
var year = 1982, // 19yy
    bigMonth = 66,
    bigDay = 2005;

// adjust day for years
var day = bigDay % 365.25;
year = year + (bigDay - day) / 365.25;

// adjust day for months
bigDay = day;
day = bigDay % 30.5;
bigMonth = bigMonth + (bigDay - day) / 30.5;

// adjust month for years
var month = bigMonth % 12;
year = year + (bigMonth - month) / 12;

console.log(year, month, day); // 1992 11 26.25
```

So it would be about the `Nov 26th, 1992`, which is pretty close to how your browser calculated it (it didn't need to estimate).